# Why aren't variables defined within the same function but in different if/else statements nonlocal to each other?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Within this function, I am trying to define a variable also defined in this function, however in different if statements. I am getting a

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'num' referenced before assignment
```

Whenever I run my function. Here's the code below:

```
def draw():
        global show_image

        win.fill([255,255,255])

        pygame.draw.rect(win, [0,0,0], (760, 250, 264 , 200), 1)




        if 1024 >= cursor[0] >= 760 and 450 >= cursor[1] >= 250:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, [128,128,128], (761, 251, 262 , 198))
            if click[0]:
                num = random.randint(0,17)
                show_image = True

        if show_image == True:
            win.blit(images[num], (0,0))
            win.blit(font.render(captions[num], True, [0,190,0]), (660,
550))

        win.blit(button_text, (780,270))


        pygame.display.update()
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Because this function gets called while `show_image` is `True`.

Comment: Why is that a problem?

Comment: It's a problem because if the cursor isn't within the correct range, then `num = random.randint(0,17)` isn't called.  If it's not assigned but `show_image` is `True` then `win..blit(images[num], (0,0))` will error because `num` doesn't exist.

Comment: A tip: Separate your drawing code from the event handling and the game logic. The code that checks if the area was clicked and changes the number shouldn't be in the `draw` function, but rather in the event loop. Also, use [`pygame.Rect`s](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) for the buttons because they have useful collision detection methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when show_image is true, but `1024 >= cursor[0] >= 760 and 450 >= cursor[1] >= 250` is satisfied, then `win.blit(images[num], 0, 0)` gets executed BEFORE num is defined (because num is defined in the first if statement). A way to fix this is by declaring num outside the function and then executing `global num` inside the if function.

Corrected code:

```
num = random.randint(0, 17)
def draw():
    global show_image
    global num
    win.fill([255,255,255])
    pygame.draw.rect(win, [0,0,0], (760, 250, 264 , 200), 1)
    if 1024 >= cursor[0] >= 760 and 450 >= cursor[1] >= 250:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, [128,128,128], (761, 251, 262 , 198))
        if click[0]:
            num = random.randint(0,17)
            show_image = True
    if show_image == True:
        win.blit(images[num], (0,0))
        win.blit(font.render(captions[num], True, [0,190,0]), (660,550))
    win.blit(button_text, (780,270))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

If the global variable `show_image` is `True` when the function is called but the cursor is out of the bounds defined by your first if-statement (or in bounds, but `click[0]` is `False`), then `num` will never be defined, so when the `if show_image == True:` statement runs, it tries to use `num` before `num` is ever assigned a value.